# Connecting Keras model with no output

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, classification

I have 2 models that I am using for a classification:

```
morf_model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(800, activation=tf.nn.tanh , input_shape=([np.shape(x)[1]])),
    keras.layers.Dense(800, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(600, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])
```

and

```
color_model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(800, activation=tf.nn.tanh , input_shape=([np.shape(col_x)[1]])),
    keras.layers.Dense(800, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(600, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])
```

that I want to **remove the output layer** (the layer with 2 nodes),freeze them and connect it with a new model

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation=tf.nn.tanh , input_shape=([np.shape(last_x)[1]])),
    keras.layers.Dense(800, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(600, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(300, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(50, activation=tf.nn.tanh),
    keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
])
```

so the model will look like

```
morf_model ---|
              |--->model 
color_model  -|
```

is it possible?

thankyou

Comment: Using the `keras` tag here would be expected (added).

Answer (score 2):

Yes , 
Using the `Keras functional API` brings you all possibilities.
check it out here

https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models

You can remove the last layer of both the networks and still connect them , Now , make sure that your second last layer is the output layer.

eg:

```
merge = Concatenate()([morf_model.output,color_model.output])
model = Model(inputs=[morf_model.input,color_model.input], outputs=output)
```